# Recent Chats and Bookmarked Chats sub-menu is not visible on Skype AppIndicator

Tags: 14.04, indicator, skype, menu

Each time I move my mouse point to Recent Chats and Bookmarked Chats on Skype AppIndicator, it did not appear any sub-menu. I just see a dim patch in there.
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and Skype 4.3
I tried to remove and re-install Skype but it didn't work
Could some one give me an advice?

Comment: Same thing here, with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Skype 4.3. I have deleted the ~/.Skype folder after update from 4.2 (it was not working otherwise), but the problem it's still here (i.e., no Recent Chats). [Added comment in Launchpad as suggested by Gunnar]

Answer (score 0):

At https://launchpad.net/bugs/1280109 I reported the same observation as regards the "Recent Chats" and "Contact Groups" sub menus on Skype 4.3.

I had upgraded from an existing Skype 4.2 installation, so I had a previous history in my `~/.Skype` folder. The problem disappeared when I moved away that folder, so my conclusion is that there is something in the history recorded by Skype < 4.3 that is not compatible with version 4.3.

If this proves to be the case for you too, it would be great if you could add a comment about it at https://launchpad.net/bugs/1280109